# Initialize Mercurial Repository with hg4idea in Intellij Idea

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I have created a project that I wish to push to a remote repository.

When I right-click the project in project view and "commit directory," it says there are no changes. ??

I see nothing under the Version Control->Mercurial.

I just want to avoid having to run "hg init."  Not that big a deal, but it would be nice to know.  Thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but ARE there any changes? Have you added all the changed files and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"hg init" is a one time task to create a repository, which pales into insignificance over various other activities with that repository.

It is always a good idea to create your repository manually. Once that is done, Mercurial will recognize it as a repo and allow you to "add files", commit etc. All of which you can do via  hg4idea.