# Initialize Mercurial for a project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mercurial

How does one start using Mercurial with an IntelliJ 2017 project?

➠ Am I expected to manually run a `hg init` myself, outside of IntelliJ?

[This Answer to a similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4282325/642706) suggests “Yes”, but is several years old.

---

When I go to IntelliJ > `Settings`/`Preferences` > `Version Control` and set the only item in the list to a value of `Mercurial` in the `VCS` column, and press `Apply` button, I get this error message:

> Invalid VCS root mapping
>
> The directory  is registered as a hg4idea root, but no hg4idea repositories were found there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize Mercurial Repository with hg4idea in Intellij Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878575/initialize-mercurial-repository-with-hg4idea-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Yes, the original answer you found is still correct, and it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

Menu VCS -> Import Into Version Control -> Create Mercurial Repository
[image]

Then, hit OK in the dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just call VCS -> Enable version control integration, and select Mercurial in the drop-down.
A new repository will be initialized automatically.